# BigQuery vs Cloud SQL autoscaling?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql, autoscaling

I declare that I am a beginner in using Google Cloud Platform.

I am developing a web application in react using firebase, so all data is saved on firestore.

Now I need to have a relational database, and I am very confused as to which is the best between Cloud SQL and BigQuery.

My idea was to have one part of the data on Cloud SQL and the other part on Firestore.

When an event happens, the data from Cloud SQL and firestore are merged and uploaded to BigQuery for analysis.

Example:

> On Firestore I have a product that has an array field where IDs are
> stored. These IDs are related to the Database saved on Cloud SQL. When
> an order is placed it is added to a collection on Firestore and
> appended to the database on BigQuery.

**My problem is that from what I have read there is no possibility of autoscaling on Cloud SQL, while on BigQuery it does.**

So my question is can you autoscale on CloudSQL?

If it can't be done, is it correct to use BigQuery exclusively?

Is there another solution on GCP that allows you to have a relational database but with autoscaling?

**Edit 1**

This is the very simplified model of a part of the database on CloudSQL / BigQuery

[image: Database model]

I'll use a 2/3 inner join query to get all the values I need.

I don't know how to make it non-relational and therefore be able to use firestore without having a large duplication of data, I am open to any kind of advice

Comment: SO is for coding specific questions and asking our opinion is not within the guidelines. For example questions asking "which is better; X or Y" are off topic as without understanding the entire use case, we would just be guessing. *Now I need to have a relational database*, why? You're also mixing two different types of databases and the purpose is unclear; why not just use Firebase and call it done? Most importantly, duplicating data is very common practice in NOSQL Databases - that's called *denormalizing* your data. Look it up as it's a very important topic.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I understood correctly, but I reckon you would like to get some data (from one data source), combine/process that data with the data from a Firestore collection, and load/stream the result into BigQuery. All of that - is operationally in run time. The question is about the choice of that data source - either a Cloud SQL or a BigQuery.

Am I right that from you point of view the main Cloud SQL drawback - is a lack of scalability (autoscale). And you would like to consider a BigQuery instead of the Cloud SQL due to the 'autoscale'?

It is not clear what is the rate of the request/queries you expect, and where the data is located (any requirements on a global access), so it may be difficult to discuss the situation. Anyway...

Thinking about BigQuery, in my opinion, - this is a great "database" (the best from my point of view), but mainly for analytical purposes... Each query has some 'initial' latency (the query job won't be executed faster than some threshold), which cannot be significantly minimised, and there is no binary indexes in BigQuery tables. It means that your query will take a few seconds (let's assume 3 or more) every time you run it (unless the result is taken from the cache). If the number of requests is significant - it may become expensive (in BigQuery) and expensive in the component, which is used to process that task (i.e. Cloud Function triggered by some event) - as the later has to wait (and do nothting) during the query time.
In addition, BigQuery is very good in loading or steeaming data into it, but not very good in regular data updates inside it - there are plenty of limitations. Thus, depending on your  context, it may be not very good idea to maintain operational data in BigQuery.

If I rule out the BigQuery -

1. Can we sacrifice 'autoscalability' for the Cloud SQL?
2. Can we use a Firestore collection instead of the Cloud SQL (and sacrifice the 'relational' property?
3. Can we use Cloud SQl and handle the the amount of data in tables which are used for querying, so there is no delays?

Not sure if I managed to help, but at least I provided some thoughts about the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it was very helpful to me, I have edited my question to be clearer, if you can help me again I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

'Now I need to have a relational database, and I am very confused as to which is the best between Cloud SQL and BigQuery.'

Please be aware that BigQuery cannot be used to substitute a relational Database, and it is oriented on running analytical queries, not for simple CRUD operations and queries (Like in Cloud SQL). That doesn’t mean BigQuery can’t handle normalized data and joins. It absolutely can. It just performs better on denormalized stuff because BigQuery is essentially an OLAP engine. So, denormalize whenever possible ([please read here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input#denormalize_data_whenever_possible)).

You can use read replications to scale Cloud SQL. Read Replica instances allow data from the master instance to be replicated to one or more slaves. This setup can provide increased read throughput. [Please see this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication#replication-external).